# How to redirect url with many //////////

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How redirect site.com/ddsda////////  to  site.com/ddsda/

htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [f,l]
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you write your question any better? I can't understand what you want.

Comment: Do you want to remove multiple slashes after `ddsda` only or anywhere in URL?

Answer (score 0):

Right below the `RewriteBase` line, try adding this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)//+([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ //+(\ |\?|$)
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

You need to check the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable because it is the literal request that is read by apache, it looks something like this:

```
GET /abc////// HTTP/1.1
```

The other pattern matches you make against have been normalized so all of the multiple "/"'s have been automatically removed and you won't be able to match them.